# `git -S` doesn't find all commits

Tags: git, revision-history

Consider the following typescript:

```diff
$ git clone git@github.com:laravel/framework.git
$ cd framework

$ git log --all --oneline --graph --decorate
...
| * | | | | | 07bb4d7 fix
| * | | | | | 0c2b7da Use the current timestamp as a default.
| * | | | | | 26cd65e (tag: v5.2.7) increment version

$ git show 0c2b7da
commit 0c2b7da2635f7bbbaf63d1b93fa817232bdd9d65
Author: Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Jan 7 08:01:39 2016 -0600

    Use the current timestamp as a default.

diff --git a/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php b/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php
index fca8e89..7e179aa 100755
--- a/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php
+++ b/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php
@@ -791,9 +791,9 @@ class Blueprint
      */
     public function timestamps()
     {
-        $this->timestamp('created_at');
+        $this->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();

-        $this->timestamp('updated_at');
+        $this->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
     }

     /**

$ git log -p -m --full-history 07bb4d7 -Stimestamp src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php
```

You won't see this commit in the output of the last command. But if you do:

```
$ git log -p origin/master -Stimestamp src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php
```

You'll see this one:

```diff
commit 720a116897a4cc6780fa22f34d30c5986eafc581
Author: Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Feb 3 08:13:22 2016 -0600

    make timestamps nullable by default

diff --git a/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php b/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php
index fca8e89..6cfab6f 100755
--- a/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php
+++ b/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php
@@ -779,9 +779,7 @@ class Blueprint
      */
     public function nullableTimestamps()
     {
-        $this->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();
-
-        $this->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();
+        return $this->timestamps();
     }

     /**
@@ -791,9 +789,9 @@ class Blueprint
      */
     public function timestamps()
     {
-        $this->timestamp('created_at');
+        $this->timestamp('created_at')->nullable();

-        $this->timestamp('updated_at');
+        $this->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable();
     }

     /**
@@ -803,9 +801,9 @@ class Blueprint
      */
     public function timestampsTz()
     {
-        $this->timestampTz('created_at');
+        $this->timestampTz('created_at')->nullable();

-        $this->timestampTz('updated_at');
+        $this->timestampTz('updated_at')->nullable();
     }

     /**
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I find commits that change method `timestamps`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation for `git log`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) (but with my emphasis added):

> `-S<string>`
>
> Look for differences that change the **number of occurrences** of the specified string (i.e. addition/deletion) in a file. Intended for the scripter’s use.

The commit not shown has the same *number of occurrences* of the word `timestamp` in both versions (before the change, and after).  The actual *use* of the word is different, but the *number of occurrences* is the same.

The commit that *is* shown changes the number of occurrences: the first diff-hunk replaces two copies of the word `timestamp` with just one copy of the word `timestamp` (two literal `timestamp` words are replaced with one `timestamp`-inside-the-word-`timestamps`).

You almost certainly want, instead, the `-G` flag, which is described immediately below the `-S` flag.  Note that `-G` takes a regular expression, rather than a simple string, though the word `timestamp` has no regex characters in it so for this case there is no difference.  (But you might want to use `--perl-regexp` to get full Perl style regular expressions, so that you can search for `\btimestamp\b`, meaning "the word timestamp but surrounded by non-word characters", i.e., don't match `timestamps` or `thetimestamp` or `twotimestamps`, all of which *contain* `timestamp`.)